# Android ListView - Setting adapter in a background thread to improve performance?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

## Situation

I have 3 tabs and currently when I swipe between the tabs there's a lot of lag. Each tab contains a ListView that has an image of a user, and two TextViews with the user's name and a small description (kind of like WhatsApp). Earlier each ListView would also lag and not scroll smoothly, but I went through [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) from the android developers website and then I modified my app to load the images in an AsyncTask and also implemented the ViewHolder pattern. Now, the ListView loads scrolls smoothly, but it takes time to scroll for the first time. In other words, when the ListView is scrolled for the first time it lags, but then it becomes smooth. Another thing you should know is that the data that is populated into the ListView is loaded from a SQLite DB.

## Hypothesis

I hypothesized that the reason for this is that even though I'm loading the images in an AsyncTask, because I'm reading content from a DB prior to setting the adapter, that DB access is causing the tab switch and the subsequent first-scroll to be slow.

## Question

Will reading the DB in an AsyncTask and then setting the ListView adapter in the onPostExecute method improve my performance? If yes, what's the logic behind it?

I have a bad feeling it wouldn't make a difference because the ListView will be drawn only after the data is provided through an adapter. Here, however, we're loading the data to be fed into the adapter itself from a DB in an AsyncTask.

Comment: Look into Picasso and use it to load images into the views. Loading images dynamically, particularly in an async fashion, can be quite the undertaking to make it work efficiently. Picasso will manage a lot of those efficiencies for you. I can't see the TextViews being the cause of the lag. Also look into limiting image size.

Comment: I don't see TextViews being a problem either, I just mentioned it for the sake of completeness. Loading the image into the ImageView iis not a problem either because I've implemented background loading of images as outlined in the docs. The problem however is *loading the image from the db into the memory*, prior to setting it to the ImageView.

Comment: Do that in an AsyncTask and have a loading dialog/progress bar that shows until it is done.

Comment: My tabs don't switch smoothly even when the ListView is empty, and therefore I just show a message saying you don't have any contacts or whatever. Any clue why?